# Modular design to reduce coupling in go

Tags: go, modularity

I am building a RESTful API using golang.
I am using gin-gonic framework and mgo for mongodb connection.

I am trying to build this modular... (I don't think I know exactly what I am talking about and trying to do. XD LOL)

Like all other software, my project has multiple collections and number of collections will increase in the future.

And I would like to separate each module as much as possible from other modules so that I could

1. incrementally add modules
2. reuse the code for future projects and simply add files to add feature (in this case, I probably need to make each module into a separate package)

Here is my current project structure.

- main.go - contains main function
- database.go - small function that opens connection with Db
- users.go - users collection related file
- users-controller.go - contains gin.HandlerFunc for users collection
- contents.go - contents collection related file
- contents-controller.go - contains gin.HandlerFunc for contents collection

Code
https://gist.github.com/letsdevus/5121381be7cb1065e62ae403f14cd562

`users` and `contents` modules are totally independent.
Removing contents*.go files from project will cleanly disable contents module in the project.
Adding some non-dependent modules is very easy as well. No code to touch but simply adding files is all I need to do.

I would give myself kudos for that.

But now I am trying to add a module that has to interact with other modules.

It's called 'activities' module.
This module has to interact with other modules to track of what activities are occurring.

For example, when insert happens on users collection, activities module needs to know it happened so that it can record the activity.

A simple way of implementing activities module is adding a line, `activities.insert("NewUser", Id)` after `users.Insert()` is called.

The problem of this approach is very obvious.

1. I have to do this for all... the collections.
2. And more importantly, when I remove activities files from the project, I need to comment out all the activities related lines from other modules.

I want you to hear my plan to tackle this problem and advise me if it's viable or if there is any other better way.

My current possible solution: event manager

`eventmanager.go` will be added in the project as one of the base files like main.go and database.go.

**eventmanager.go**

```
package main

type EventFunc func()

type EventManager struct {
    events map[string][]EventFunc
}

func (i *EventManager) AddEvent(eventName string, fn EventFunc) {
    i.events[eventName] = append(i.events[eventName], fn)
}

func (i *EventManager) RunEvents(eventName string) {
    for _, fn := range i.events[eventName] {
        fn()
    }
}

var eventManager EventManager // Globally available
```

And in `users.go` Insert() function, I add

```
eventManger.RunEvent("usersPostInsert")
```

after `dbcUsers.Insert(&user)`.

And in init() in activities.go file, I add

```
eventManager.AddEvent("usersPostInsert", newUserActivity)
```

In the end of `activities.go`

```
func newUserActivity() {
  // Do something. For now just print a message
  log.Print("New User is Inserted!")
}
```

This way when I take off activities module, no problem occurs.

I hope you get the idea of what I am trying to do.

I just really want to know if this is a more than an OK way of tackling the problem.

p.s. If you are about to down vote this question because it's more like a codereview, just leave a comment instead. (somehow down vote makes me really uncomfortable lol)

Comment: I'll probably be alone on this one, but I would say you're overthinking/overcomplicating it and making it harder for yourself. Modular things are nice, but it adds a lot of complexity as well, and chances are you're just wasting your time on it. Also, you're doing some redundant things that could've been done in a middleware.

Comment: @JohnSmith Thanks for the comment. I do appreciate any comment. Helps me think in a different way. So yeah probably I am overthinking. lol I researched RxGo since it looked like this is what could help me but I couldn't find a solid RxGo implementation yet. Hmm... I like to but getting a grasp on how to structure modules and packages is difficult.

Comment: Keeping track of current and past state with events is a good strategy to keep different packages within their own bounds. However I suggest that you only use events to describe things that *have already happened*, instead of having a function that is executed by the event handler. Then you can use the events to reconstruct the state.
Regardless of events... You can use dependency injection to keep code modular, for example, instead of `newAccount.Insert()` use `newAccount.Insert(myMongo)`